# Update Flask Progress Bar From Txt File

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, progress-bar

I have a web app I am currently developing that has one very long step in it (~30 min) and I would like to give my users a progress bar that shows them how much of the program is complete.

The program writes the progress and estimated time remaining in a txt file like this

```
if timeProgress > pTimeProgress+0.0001:
            pTimeProgress = timeProgress
            curTime = datetime.now()
            secsLeft = (curTime-startTime).total_seconds()*(1-timeProgress)/timeProgress
            string = "{0:.2f}".format(timeProgress*100)+"%: Approximately "+"{0:.2f}".format(secsLeft)+" seconds remaining"
            print(string)
            with open('time.txt', 'w') as the_file:
                the_file.write(string)
```

This is the app.route for the post method:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form_post():
    placeholder = "https://via.placeholder.com/2048"
    preview_src = placeholder

    if request.method == "POST":

        req = request.form
        
        if 'Preview' in req:
           ...
        elif 'Submit' in req: #this is the post request that kicks everything off
            lat = req["lat"]
            long = req["long"]
            key = req["apiKey"]

            get_static_img(lat, long, key) #creates geoImage.png
            do_thing(lat, long, key)
            preview_src = url_for('static', filename='geoImage.png')
            with open("warpAnimation.py") as f:
                code = compile(f.read(), "warpAnimation.py", 'exec')
                exec(code)
            with open("makeAnimation.py") as f:
                code = compile(f.read(), "makeAnimation.py", 'exec')
                exec(code)
```

Also I am using bootstrap for the progress bar, but I already know how to do this. Most of my confusion comes from the flask side.

Thank you